# Microsecond Time Stamps in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a microsecond string to timestamp using the following syntax in pyspark. However, I seem to be getting a `null` when I convert. I am using Spark 2.2

My string looks like `20180503-07:05:00.008288`

I'm using the following code to convert to Timestamp

```
df = df.withColumn("my_time_timestamp",to_timestamp("my_time", "yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing here?

Comment: I don't think `to_timestamp` works with microseconds like that. Take out the `.SSSSSS` and it should work or write a UDF to achieve more granularity.

Comment: @philantrovert you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Interestingly `spark.sql("""SELECT to_timestamp(substring("20180503-07:05:00.008288", 0, 23), "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")""").show` works (stripping one digit from the input), so it looks more like a bug.