# How to stop timestamp in pyspark from dropping trailing zeroes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Spark dataframe in where the Timestamp is in milliseconds.

```
+-----------------------+
|CALC_TS                |
+-----------------------+
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|    
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|
```

I want to make it show microseconds like so:

```
+--------------------------+
|CALC_TS                   |
+--------------------------+
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043000|
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043000|
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043000|
```

So basically I would like the milliseconds portion to show in terms of microseconds. In the above example, the `43` milliseconds from the 1st dataframe would be `43 thousand` microseconds as shown in the seconds dataframe.

I have tried:

```
df.withColumn('TIME', to_timestamp('CALC_TS', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))
```

and

```
df.withColumn('TIME', col('CALC_TS').cast("timestamp"))
```

But they are giving the same result and stripping the last 3 zeroes. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648154/microsecond-time-stamps-in-pyspark

Comment: @Paul, unfortunately, that doesn't work for me. I came across that post when looking into it. Thank you tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_timestamp(timestamp_str[,fmt])` accepts a string and returns a timestamp (type). If your `CALC_TS` is already a timestamp as you said, you should rather use `df.withColumn('TIME', date_format('CALC_TS','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))` to format it to string, with microseconds precision. From [Spark reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html):

> o Fraction: Use one or more (up to 9) contiguous 'S' characters, e,g
> SSSSSS, to parse and format fraction of second. For parsing, the
> acceptable fraction length can be [1, the number of contiguous ‘S’].
> **For formatting, the fraction length would be padded to the number of
> contiguous ‘S’ with zeros.** Spark supports datetime of micro-of-second
> precision, which has up to 6 significant digits, but can parse
> nano-of-second with exceeded part truncated.

For Spark 2.4, and just to make it **look like** the precision of a timestamp field is microseconds, perhaps you can "fake" trailing zeroes while formatting it like this: `date_format('CALC_TS','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS000')`

Comment: So i think i might not have framed my requirement clearly. I tried your method and it game the same result as @blackbishop. I am getting `2021-01-27 01:35:05.000043` instead of `2021-01-27 01:35:05.043000`. The idea is to depict the result in terms of microseconds. So `43` milliseconds is `43,000` microseconds

Comment: @thentangler What is your Spark version?

Comment: Spark version is 2.4.6

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26424 could be related? I updated the answer.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you. However, I am not quite adept at deciphering github posts. It looks a lot like greek to me lol. I surmised that one can use `DateFormatClass`, `ToUnixTimestamp`, `FromUnixTime` and `UnixTime ` to include microseconds. So would that mean i should use `f.ToUnixTimestamp('CALC_TS', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")` instead of `f.unix_timestamp` ?

Comment: The related part in that JIRA was `Fix Version/s: 3.0.0` i.e. upgrading your Spark to 3.0 should fix it automagically :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rpad](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#rpad).

Right pad with trailing zeros upto the expected length of your timestamp. In your case, a length of 26 characters (for format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('CALC_TS_1', col('CALC_TS').cast("timestamp"))\
    .withColumn('CALC_TS_1', rpad(col('CALC_TS_1').cast('string'),26,'0'))\
    .show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|CALC_TS                   |CALC_TS_1                 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043   |2021-01-27 01:35:05.043000|
|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043567|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043567|
+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column`CALC_TS` is of type string, first convert to `TimestampType` using `to_timestamp` and `unix_timestamp` functions then using `date_format` you can format it with 6 fractions in milliseconds :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.printSchema()

#root
# |-- CALC_TS: string (nullable = true)

df1 = df.withColumn(
   'TIME',
   F.to_timestamp(
       F.unix_timestamp('CALC_TS', "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") # seconds
       + F.substring_index('CALC_TS', '.', -1).cast('float') / 1000 # milliseconds part
   )
).withColumn(
   "TIME_FORMAT",
   F.date_format("TIME", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
#|CALC_TS                |TIME                   |TIME_FORMAT               |
#+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+
#|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|2021-01-27 01:35:05.000043|
#|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|2021-01-27 01:35:05.000043|
#|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|2021-01-27 01:35:05.043|2021-01-27 01:35:05.000043|
#+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------+

#root
# |-- CALC_TS: string (nullable = true)
# |-- TIME: timestamp (nullable = true)
# |-- TIME_FORMAT: string (nullable = true)
```

If the column is already of type timestamp, simply use `date_format` as in the above code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as mentioned below in reply to mazaneicha's answer, I am looking for a way to show the milliseconds in terms of microseconds. With your suggested method, it is converting 43 `milliseconds` to 43 `microseconds`, which would be inaccurate.