# Spark SQL doesn't always return 3 digit for the milliseconds

Tags: apache-spark

I'm extracting data from a Apache Phoenix table using the spark framework.

The query :

```
"(select EVENT_TIME FROM TRADING_EVENTS WHERE EVENT_TIME >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-14 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS', 'GMT+2') and EVENT_TIM <= TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-09-14 23:59:59.999', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS', 'GMT+2')"
```

The code :

```
DataFrame result =
                sqlContext.read().format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").jdbc(zkUrl, sql, new Properties()));
result.show(100);
```

The query execute itself and I have result but I noticed that some timestamp weren't formatted the same way:

```
2021-09-14 00:00:00.004
2021-09-14 00:00:00.004
2021-09-14 00:00:00.005
2021-09-14 00:00:00.006
2021-09-14 00:00:00.006
2021-09-14 00:00:00.008
2021-09-14 00:00:00.008
2021-09-14 00:00:00.009
2021-09-14 00:00:00.009
2021-09-14 00:00:00.01
2021-09-14 00:00:00.01
-> 2021-09-14 00:00:00.10
2021-09-14 00:00:00.014
-> 2021-09-14 00:00:00.02
2021-09-14 00:00:00.02
-> 2021-09-14 00:00:00.0
2021-09-14 00:00:00.028
```

In the first place I thought it was because spark wouldn't bother display the remaining 0 for the milliseconds but even assuming this I have some very inconsistent results such as:

- 2021-09-14 00:00:00.10
- 2021-09-14 00:00:00.02
- 2021-09-14 00:00:00.4
- 2021-09-14 00:00:00.004

Is there a way I could tune my job to not have this ? Also when i display the line from the Phoenix database directly, all the lines are properly formated.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert to the timestamp the date in the database is converted to the internal spark representation of a timestamp, and when you do `show` it performs some default toString function of the type.

In order to present a uniformly padded string, I suggest you do something like:

```
df.withColumn("formatted_timestamp", date_format(col('timestamp'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
```

which will pad your timestamps with zeroes.

[more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65946517/15433308)